# How to get Blockchain.com Websockets Address Balance Tracking to work?

Tags: typescript, websocket, blockchain

## Problem

I'm implementing an Address Balance tracking service using Blockchain.com's Websockets. I'm following this API Docs page:

- https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/api/api_websocket

I managed to find a Bitcoin address that does a lot of transactions each day, which is perfect for Address Balance tracking:

- `bc1qw8wrek2m7nlqldll66ajnwr9mh64syvkt67zlu`
- https://mempool.space/address/bc1qw8wrek2m7nlqldll66ajnwr9mh64syvkt67zlu

So I subscribed to that address with the method described in the API Docs:

```
{
  "op": "addr_sub",
  "addr": "bc1qw8wrek2m7nlqldll66ajnwr9mh64syvkt67zlu"
}
```

But their Websocket is not notifying me each time a new transaction is executed.

## Code explanation

This is my working code, you just need to install websockets ('ws' library) and run it in a typescript environment. It's straightforward: I just have an `init()` function that creates the WebSocket and tells the Websocket what to do on "open", "close", "message", "data" and "error", which is basically just logging what data is received. Once that part's done, I subscribe to the address mentioned above and wait for a response. I also do a ping every **5 seconds** to get a simple heartbeat.

```js
import * as ws from 'ws';

export class BlockchainDotCom {
  /**
   * The Websocket instance
   * @type {ws.WebSocket}
   * @private
   */
  private websocket: ws.WebSocket;

  /**
   * Counter for how many msgs were received.
   * @type {number}
   */
  static msgCounter = 0;

  /**
   * Init the websocket
   * @return {Promise<void>}
   */
  async init(): Promise<void> {
    this.websocket = await this.createWebsocket();
    this.setOnMessage();
    this.setOnData();
    this.setOnError();
    await sleep(1000);
    await this.subscribeToAddress('bc1qw8wrek2m7nlqldll66ajnwr9mh64syvkt67zlu');
  }

  /**
   * Pings the websocket for the latest block.
   */
  ping(): void {
    this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 'ping_block' }));
  }

  /**
   * Subscribe to address, receiving notifications of new txs.
   * @TODO Doesn't work
   * @param {string} address
   * @return {Promise<void>}
   */
  async subscribeToAddress(address: string): Promise<void> {
    this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 'addr_sub', addr: address }));
    console.log(`Subscribed to address ` + address);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a WebSocket object with instructions on opening the socket, receiving messages and closing the socket.
   * @return {Promise<WebSocket>}
   */
  private async createWebsocket(): Promise<WebSocket> {
    const websocket = new ws.WebSocket('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');

    // What to do when the Websocket opens
    websocket.on('open', () => {
      console.log('Blockchain.com Websocket open');
    });

    // If we don't wait, the websocket won't be open yet and the this.ping() Interval will throw an error.
    await sleep(2000);
    const interval = setInterval(() => this.ping(), 5000);

    // What to do when the Websocket closes
    websocket.on('close', async () => {
      console.log('Blockchain.com Websocket closed');
      clearInterval(interval);
      websocket.terminate();
      await sleep(10000);
      return this.createWebsocket(); // Auto restart if it closes
    });
    return websocket;
  }

  /**
   * Tells the Websocket what should happen in the "message" event.
   * @return {void}
   */
  private setOnMessage(): void {
    this.websocket.on('message', (data) => {
      let msg = data.toString();
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(msg);
      if (parsedData['op'] === 'block') {
        msg = `   Current Block Index: ${parsedData['x']['blockIndex']}`;
      }
      if (parsedData['op'] === 'utx') {
        msg = `   New Transaction Detected: ${parsedData}`;
      }
      console.log(`Msg #${BlockchainDotCom.msgCounter++}: ${getDate()}`);
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Tells the Websocket what should happen in the "data" event.
   * @return {void}
   */
  private setOnData(): void {
    this.websocket.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('Code#8888');
      let msg = data.toString();
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(msg);
      if (parsedData['op'] === 'block') {
        msg = `   Current Block Index: ${parsedData['x']['blockIndex']}`;
      }
      if (parsedData['op'] === 'utx') {
        msg = `   New Transaction Detected: ${parsedData}`;
      }
      console.log(`Msg #${BlockchainDotCom.msgCounter++}: ${getDate()}`);
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Tells the Websocket what should happen in the "error" event.
   * @return {void}
   */
  private setOnError(): void {
    this.websocket.on('error', (data) => {
      console.log('Code#9999');
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
}

// ================================ UTIL FUNCTIONS ================================
/**
 * Wait for a given amount of milliseconds.
 * @param {number} ms
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
const sleep = (ms: number): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
};

/**
 * Get a full date with time as string.
 * @return {string}
 */
const getDate = (): string => {
  const now = new Date();
  let secs = now.getSeconds().toString();
  let mins = now.getMinutes().toString();
  if (secs.length === 1) {
    secs = `0${secs}`;
  }
  if (mins.length === 1) {
    mins = `0${mins}`;
  }
  return `${now.getDate()}-${now.getMonth()}-${now.getFullYear()}   ${now.getHours()}:${mins}:${secs}`;
};

// ================================================================================


// Start
new BlockchainDotCom().init().then(() => console.log('BlockchainDotCom Instance has started and is running'));
```

## Observations

This is a sample Output. You can see that the Block Index has increased, so a new block has been mined. But the transactions in that block weren't reported. I've let this program run for hours, but all that was ever logged is the ping msg.

```
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #85: 18-9-2022   12:47:29
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #86: 18-9-2022   12:47:34
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #87: 18-9-2022   12:47:39
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #88: 18-9-2022   12:47:44
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #89: 18-9-2022   12:47:49
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #90: 18-9-2022   12:47:55
   Current Block Index: 759207
Msg #91: 18-9-2022   12:47:59
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #92: 18-9-2022   12:48:05
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #93: 18-9-2022   12:48:10
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #94: 18-9-2022   12:48:15
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #95: 18-9-2022   12:48:20
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #96: 18-9-2022   12:48:25
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #97: 18-9-2022   12:48:30
   Current Block Index: 759209
Msg #98: 18-9-2022   12:48:35
   Current Block Index: 759209
```

But new address transactions, there's no response. It also doesn't send an error.

Oddly enough when I subscribe to receiving notifications of **new blocks**, then it **does** notify me:

```
{
  "op": "blocks_sub"
}
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong? Have other people got it working?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am using some API endpoint it will table time to respond it will only respond when it found new block is created